# React Forms: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, dictionary, undefined

guys, I'm starting out with React and decided to start learning forms.

I currently have this code, but it's throwing me an error(listed at the end), to my understanding, it's probably because the initial state or the one in componentDidMount is not getting passed to my Select component.
If you can help me out with the fix it's great but also point me in the direction of some lectures that talk about that topic or a couple of tutorials.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import FormContainer from './containers/FormContainer';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <FormContainer />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

FormContainer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Select from '../components/Select';

class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breaksStatusOptions: [],
      selectedBreakStatus: ''
    };
    this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
    this.handleStatusSelect = this.handleStatusSelect.bind(this);
  }

  ComponentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      breakStatusOptions: ['Green', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Black'],
      selectedBreakStatus: 'Black'
    });
  }

  handleStatusSelect(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedBreakStatus: e.target.value }, () =>
      console.log('Breaks status options', this.state.selectedBreakStatus)
    );
  }

  handleClearForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      selectedBreakStatus: ''
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="container">
        <Select
          name={'breaksStatus'}
          placeholder={'Choose status of breaks'}
          controlFunc={this.handleStatusSelect}
          options={this.state.breakStatusOptions}
          selectedOption={this.state.selectedBreakStatus}
        />
        <RaisedButton
          label="Clear"
          secondary={true}
          onClick={this.handleClearForm}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default FormContainer;
```

Select.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Select = props =>
  <div className="form-group">
    <select
      name={props.name}
      value={props.selectedOption}
      onChange={props.controlFunc}
      className="form-select"
    >
      <option value="">{props.placeholder}</option>
      {props.options.map(opt => {
        return (
          <option key={opt} value={opt}>{opt}</option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
  </div>;

Select.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  selectedOption: PropTypes.string,
  controlFunc: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string
};

export default Select;
```

---

and I'm currently getting this error output:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Select
*C:/javascript/react/search-app/src/components/Select.js:13*

```
  10 |   className="form-select"
  11 | >
  12 |   <option value="">{props.placeholder}</option>
> 13 |   {props.options.map(opt => {
  14 |     return (
  15 |       <option key={opt} value={opt}>{opt}</option>
  16 |     );
```

Comment: Your spelling of `breaksStatusOptions` is wrong (declared with **s**, but passed without). Strange that `Select.propTypes` does not warn you before: are you testing with a production build?

Comment: you have **typos** in the your code: **1** extra s in `breaksStatusOptions` **2.** capital C in lifecycle method it should be `componentDidMount`. voted to close the ques.

Comment: I don't have a tutorial or guide to give you other than read the docs. I also recommend you to use console.log(). I.e console.log("Value of Options: " + this.state.breakStatusOptions) to check if the value is what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Yes the typos where the problem.

Comment: How do I close the question ir vote for it.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have misspelled `ComponentDidMount`. It should start with lowercase: `componentDidMount`. Otherwise its a different method react will never call.

Comment: The problem lies in the mispell of `breaksStatusOptions` in the render function. Also with wrong `ComponentDidMount`, that error message should not be thrown, because that state variable should be an empty array however (empty, but not undefined). And also when fixed with **c**, the problem will persist. Anyway, yes, it's a double mispell